# Content Approval

Tags: document, library

Is there a way to make it so that if the person publishing a document is the same person who approves documents that they can just publish without the added step of having to approve something that they already approve of?

Comment: I believe if the person who approves the content also has publish rights, the page will be published upon approval. That is how ours is working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with simple list configuration\permissions. I think you can do it with simple SPD workflow. Remember to set the workflow settings to begin on create and on edit. I recommend trying this and doing some testing to see if it behaves as expected. Thanks!

[image]